# How do I add more info onto an excel graph?

Tags: excel

After creating a pie chart on excel, is there anyway that I can add more information(separate from the pie chart) on the side of the graph? i.e. I have a pie chart with the percentage ratio of doctors and engineers, on the side, I want to have it show the total salary of the combined professions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the chart tools format tab, you should be able to insert a shape.  There's a text box shape that you can insert and then add whatever extra information you want to add.